# I would like to see a document that describes the various REST/Curl commands that the Solr server accepts

Tags: solr

I have done an extensive search and found example curl commands contain REST requests,
but I have not come across a document that lists all of the available commands and their
options. Does such a document exist?

Comment: Once you know the Solr flags you can mix it, for example some calls may include a facet other no, it will depends on your requirements. Here you are the docs for reference: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Answer (score 0):

The good places to start are the following:

- [Solr Reference Guide: Searching](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Searching)
- [Solr Common Query Parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)
- [Solr Query Syntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) (as @Wils commented above)
- [XML Messages for Updating a Solr Index](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages)

Comment: Here is an example of the kind of information I am looking for.

http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=
<delete><query>id:298253</query></delete>&commit=true


http://blog.dileno.com/archive/201106/delete-documents-from-solr-index-by-query/

Comment: Added link to XML Messages for Updates above.